# Need a robust, efficient Python serializer

Tags: python, json, serialization, pickle

I'm trying to serialize a Python object that has a mix of data types -- native Python, numpy, subclasses of built-in Python. Pickle, and cPickle, are robust enough to handle all the data types, but I reach the size limit (>300MB); I know this because upon loading the pickled object I can see not the full object was serialized. Looking for a more efficient alternative to cPickle I've tried the following, but nothing works for the data types: json, simplejson, custom subclass of json to convert numpy types to native Python, marshal (doesn't handle subclasses of built-in types, like `defaultdict`), MessagePack. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Size limit? The pickle protocol and implementations have some limitations, but I don't think there are any size limitations near the 300 MB mark. Can you give some simple, runnable example code that constructs a huge object, pickles it, and unpickles it, such that the unpickled result doesn't match the original object?

Comment: @lordingtar yes but it is unable to handle some custom data types.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on **why** you're serializing I would highly recommend looking at the [Protocol Buffer API](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

> Protocol buffers are Google's language-neutral, platform-neutral, extensible mechanism for serializing structured data – think XML, but smaller, faster, and simpler. You define how you want your data to be structured once, then you can use special generated source code to easily write and read your structured data to and from a variety of data streams and using a variety of languages.

If that sounds like it fits what your intentions are, I would suggest taking the time to read through all their documentation.

There's even a [Python specific tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial)

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to avoid the overhead of implementing a whole API, but it may be necessary. And why this over [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org/)?

Comment: Mostly because I have not heard of Cap'n Proto yet :)